# SharePoint 2007 Warmup Script (Alternative to Http Request)

Tags: c#, http, sharepoint, authentication, xmlhttprequest

At the moment I am trying to HTTP response request in my Sharepoint WarmUp script, however for this, I will have to use this code

```
 using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath))
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(line);
                        request.Proxy = null;

                        if ((userName == null) || (userName == ""))
                        {
                            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
                            myCache.Add(new Uri(line), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(userName, password, DomainName));
                            request.Credentials = myCache;
                        }

                        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                        using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                        {
                            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            reader.Close();
                            dataStream.Close();
                            response.Close();
                        }

                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }
```

**I am not suppose to use any User Account to get response, however I can use Default Credentials that only works when am logged in at server, otherwise they wont gonna work i guess.**

Is there any other way of doing it, can't use powershell as its MOSS not sharepoint 2010

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You CAN use Powershell for the warm-up script. You can call stsadm command, make HTTP requests and even use the server object model once you do the proper imports.

[This post](http://www.paulgrimley.com/2010/02/powershell-warmup-script-for-sharepoint.html) uses powershell to retrieve available sites using stsadm. Once the script retrieves this list, it instantiates a WebClient object and hits each site URL.

If you only want to hit the sites in a list, you can simply use a WebClient object to do this.

Comment: cheers for the answers, but STSADM to make http requests never heard about it before

Comment: You don't *use* STSADM to make http requests, they are two different things.  Notice the comma in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you have a working Search Service within your SSP, you can configure a scheduled crawl. Not only you'll benefit from up to date crawl results but your site will be warm-up natively without the need of an additional job doing it "just for warming up".